# Laravel model events for attach/detach

Tags: events, laravel, model

I have 3 tables, *products*, *taxonomies* and *product_taxonomy*, as you can tell the 3rd table is a pivoting table. In *taxonomies* table, I hold a field called *num_products* which keeps track of the quantity of products that belongs to this taxonomy. Now how can I trigger a model event every time a product is attached to or detached from a taxonomy? I want to update that *num_products* value in the model event.

Comment: https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot

Comment: Did you check `Notifiable` trait? It seems like you need to trigger NOTIFY with database, and then handle it with framework.

Answer (score -5):

Laravel models have events that you can hook into. You have the following options:

- creating
- created
- updating
- updated
- saving
- saved
- deleting
- deleted
- restoring
- restored

You'd code it like this:

```
User::creating(function($user)
{
     if ( ! $user->isValid()) return false;
});
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

Or you could use Model Observers that are baked in. You have the following options:

- creating
- updating
- saving

You would write a method on your model:

```
class UserObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        //
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

You can then register then register the observer:

```
User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question is for attach and detach methods

Comment: It should be a starting point. If you are listening for that event on the model, you can then trigger whatever you want based off the back of it - eg, attach/detach or whatever you want. Does that make sense?